# Facebook login doesnot work

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I made a **windows phone 7** app that uses facebook...it worked fine until a week back and now none of the previous facebook logins work....the webbrowser does not navigate to the expected url and stays blank...please help... i have also tried with the link - but no success, the browser just does not redirect to anywhere! Please help

http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx
http://windowsphoneaalto.org/2012/01/facebook-log-in-with-a-class/

This one is with updated but still the same issue
http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx

Unable to retrieve the accesstoken.

If anyone can point me to the right place or provide a code that works it will be awesome

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here it is - a blog post explaining it all, plus the working code:

http://igrali.com/2012/06/05/facebook-authentication-from-windows-phone-app/